transpose cells that contains also images
enter image description hereTranspose, including images
Hello Everyone!
Transpose in excel, like I've seen, is not a difficult thing to do.
But how do you do that when you have images you want to include?
The things I have tried to do don't copy the images to the transposed result
I have tried copy-paste special with transpose and the transpose function,
Everything I have tried copies values at cells but not the images.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
